# Generic class which generic is itself a generic

Tags: swift, generic-programming

So I have a generic class `FirstClass<T: SomeProtocol>`, and I have a second class (which inherit from `NSObject`) where it contains an array of `FirstClass`, and have functions that return element of the array (so returning a `FirstClass<T>`).

Actually I am having some trouble with the syntax.

`SecondClass<F>: NSObject where F == FirstCall<S>, S: SomeProtocol {}`
*I think this is the declaration which illustrate the best what I want to achieve*.

Here I have an error: `Use of undeclared type 'T'`.

I would like to know if this could be achieve with a specific syntax or if I take a bad path.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this

```
protocol SomeProtocol {

}

class FirstClass<T: SomeProtocol> {

}

class SecondClass<F,T:SomeProtocol>:NSObject where F:FirstClass<T> {

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately it doesn't compile... When I comment I don't have any problem but when I uncomment it I've got a `Swift Compiler Error` :(

Comment: thats strange, seems to compile fine for me, with swift 3. What version of swift are you using?

Comment: `Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1)` with `Xcode 8.2.1`.

Comment: I deleted the DerivedData, I cleaned the project but still that `Swift Compiler Error`...

Comment: Have you tried the code in a playground? I just tried adding some foos and bars to those types in a playground to check and it really does work.

Comment: Yes it works so I accept your answer. I'm gonna investigate to find the problem on my side.\